# How to get all photos on phone and show list of photos on a Flatlist in React Native

Tags: react-native, image, expo, react-native-flatlist, camera-roll

I wanted to find a library that could support getting all the photos from the phone and displaying the list of captured images on a Flatlist, and I ran this project on Expo. How to do this?

I tried using the library
react-native-cameraroll but it seems when running on Expo it didn't work, is there any other way to handle this?

Comment: **react-native-image-picker** --> it's another, you can try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use expo-image-picker

```
npm i expo-image-picker
```

OR

```
yarn add expo-image-picker
```

Here is official Documentation [Expo Image Picker](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use @react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll

```
npm i @react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll
```

use getPhotos method and it also supports pagination.

```
CameraRoll.getPhotos(params)
```

more details :- [@react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll#getphotos)